# adding confirmation before submit form in Apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am trying to add a confirmation box before submitting a form in apex. Any ideas of how i can achieve that?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   response = response2();

  function response2(){
  apex.confirm("Are you sure  you want to submit?)}
</script>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This could be achieved without any custom JavaScript code...

1) Set the button which submits the form to action "Defined by Dynamic Action" and give the button a static id

[image: button definition]

2) Define a new Dynamic Action which executes when this Button is pressed

3) This DA then have to native actions:

```
- Confirm

- Submit (Request / Button Name: The static id of your button)
```

[image: DA definition]

Comment: Thanks a bunch Daniel.

Comment: Cleanest way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to define the behavior of the submit button to "Redirect to URL". Then in the Target URL place the following javascript code;

```
javascript:apex.confirm('Are you sure?','REQUEST');
```

For example, this is the default behavior of the delete button:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that you're submitting a form by pushing the `P1_BTN_SUBMIT` button.

Set its *action* to *Redirect to URL* whose contents is

```
javascript:if(confirm('Are you sure??')){doSubmit('P1_BTN_SUBMIT');}
```